# Change language Laravel4 using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I am trying to change language from English to French using Laravel4 without refreshing the page (ajax), and to remember the user's choice, i store it in the current session, the ajax request is working properly, but the language is not changing only after i refresh the entire page (F5), this is an example of what i'm trying to do, here is my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <title>Test Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div">{{ trans('test.welcome') }}</div>  <br />
{{ trans('test.test') }}
<a id="change_language" href="javascript:void(0);">Change language</a>

<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);">
    <input id="name" type="text" />
    <input id="go" type="submit" value="Go" />
    <div id="feedback"></div>
</form>
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/ajax.js') }}
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my ajax request:

```
$("#change_language").click(function(){

        $('#feedback').html('<img src="./img/loading.gif" alt="Loading ..."/>');
        $.ajax({
            url:'change-language',
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta').attr('content')
            },
            success:function(result){
                $('#feedback').html(result);    
          }});
        });
```

this is my route.php file:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function() {

    Route::post('change-language', array(
        'as'    => 'change-language',
        'uses'  => 'AjaxController@changeLanguage'
        ));

    });
));
```

and here is my function inside my controller:

```
public function changeLanguage()
{
    Session::put('lang', 'fr');
    return 'success';
}
```

And this is the how i store user's language inside App/start/global.php

```
App::setLocale(Session::get('lang', Config::get('App.locale')));
```

So what i'm asking is: is there any way to refresh only specific parts in my page e.g the `div` that has `id="div"` without refreshing the entire page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to reload the whole page, as the strings are rendered during the time the blade files are parsed. The Ajax request saves the used locale in a session for you, but does not render your page again.

If you want to change the page content without reloading, you have to do it with JavaScript:

- Send the 'locale change' request with Ajax
- Return the strings you want to change (as a JSON object for example)
- Change the desired DOM elements to the received locale with JS

This can be (depending on the amount of elements you want to change) quiet much work. I still suggest reloading the page, I don't think it changes the usability of your webpage.

Comment: Well, it seems like it's the only solution, as you said it's a good solution, i think this is the right answer i was looking for, thanks :)